# do while para número diferente de 0 em C

Tags: c, do-while

Eu preciso que o programa pare quando o numero do consumidor for 0. Então, coloquei um do `while` dizendo que enquanto o numero do consumidor for diferente de 0 ele continua o programa e quando o numero do consumidor for 0, ele termine o programa. Acontece que mesmo digitando o 0, o programa continua.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    struct pessoas
    {

        int codTC; //codigo do consumidor para falar se é 1-Residencial 2-Comercial 3-Industrial
        int num; //numero do consumidor (vou colocar o numero referente ao cod para nao confundir)
        float kwh; //Quilowatt-hora

    };

    struct pessoas consumidor[16];

    float total, totalT, consumo1, consumo2, media;
    int i;

    printf("\nExercício desenvolvido considerando a tarifa do CIP - Contribuição Municipal\n");

    do
    {

        printf("\nTipo de consumidor, digite:\n1 - Residencial\n2 - Comercial\n3 - Industrial: ");
        scanf("%i", &consumidor[i].codTC);
        fflush(stdin);

        if (consumidor[i].codTC == 1)
        {

            printf("\nResidencial");

            printf("\n\nDigite o numero do consumidor: ");
            scanf("%i", &consumidor[i].num);

            printf("\nDigite a quantidade de kWh consumidos durante o mes: ");
            scanf("%f", &consumidor[i].kwh);

            //O total do valor sem tarifa, ou seja o custo total para cada consumidor;
            total = consumidor[i].kwh * 0.3;

            //O total do valor com tarifa, ou seja o total + tarifas
            totalT = total + 5.17;

            consumo1 = consumidor[i].kwh;


        }
        else if (consumidor[i].codTC == 2)
        {

            printf("\nComercial");

            printf("\n\nDigite o numero do consumidor: ");
            scanf("%i", &consumidor[i].num);

            printf("\nDigite a quantidade de kWh consumidos durante o mes: ");
            scanf("%f", &consumidor[i].kwh);

            total = consumidor[i].kwh * 0.5;

            //O total do valor com tarifa, ou seja o total + tarifas
            totalT = total + 5.17;

            consumo2 = consumidor[i].kwh;



        }
        else if (consumidor[i].codTC == 3)
        {

            printf("\nIndustrial");

            printf("\n\nDigite o numero do consumidor: ");
            scanf("%i", &consumidor[i].num);

            printf("\nDigite a quantidade de kWh consumidos durante o mes: ");
            scanf("%f", &consumidor[i].kwh);

            total = consumidor[i].kwh * 0.7;

            //O total do valor com tarifa, ou seja o total + tarifas
            totalT = total + 5.17;

        }

        media = consumo1 + consumo2 / 2;


        printf("\nO total de consumo e %.2f\n", total);
        printf("\nO custo total e %.2f\n", totalT);
        printf("\nA media de consumo dos consumidores 1 e 2 e %.2f\n", media);

    } while(consumidor[i].num != 0);


    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás a ler para `consumidor[i].codTC` mas a verificar `consumidor[i].num`.

```
scanf("%i", &consumidor[i].codTC);

// ...

while(consumidor[i].num != 0)
```

Só lês para `consumidor[i].num` quando a primeira leitura for `1`, `2`, ou `3`. Se a primeira leitura for `0`, o `consumidor[i].num` fica com um valor inválido.

Comment: Ah, entendi. Nossa, muito obrigada. Um erro tão simples que me levou umas boas horas tentando resolver. Obrigada mesmo! ;)

Answer (score 3):

O código sequer compila. A variável `i` não varia. Tem várias situações onde pode ocorrer um erro aí e tem coisas no código que eu faria muito diferente, mas vou só resolver o problema apresentado:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    struct pessoas {
        int codTC; //codigo do consumidor para falar se é 1-Residencial 2-Comercial 3-Industrial
        int num; //numero do consumidor (vou colocar o numero referente ao cod para nao confundir)
        float kwh; //Quilowatt-hora
    };
    struct pessoas consumidor[16];
    float total, totalT, consumo1, consumo2;
    int i = 0;
    printf("\nExercício desenvolvido considerando a tarifa do CIP - Contribuição Municipal\n");
    do {
        printf("\nTipo de consumidor, digite:\n1 - Residencial\n2 - Comercial\n3 - Industrial: ");
        scanf("%i", &consumidor[i].codTC);
        fflush(stdin);
        if (consumidor[i].codTC == 1) {
            printf("\nResidencial");
            printf("\n\nDigite o numero do consumidor: ");
            scanf("%i", &consumidor[i].num);
            printf("\nDigite a quantidade de kWh consumidos durante o mes: ");
            scanf("%f", &consumidor[i].kwh);
            //O total do valor sem tarifa, ou seja o custo total para cada consumidor;
            total = consumidor[i].kwh * 0.3;
            //O total do valor com tarifa, ou seja o total + tarifas
            totalT = total + 5.17;
            consumo1 = consumidor[i].kwh;
        } else if (consumidor[i].codTC == 2) {
            printf("\nComercial");
            printf("\n\nDigite o numero do consumidor: ");
            scanf("%i", &consumidor[i].num);
            printf("\nDigite a quantidade de kWh consumidos durante o mes: ");
            scanf("%f", &consumidor[i].kwh);
            total = consumidor[i].kwh * 0.5;
            //O total do valor com tarifa, ou seja o total + tarifas
            totalT = total + 5.17;
            consumo2 = consumidor[i].kwh;
        } else if (consumidor[i].codTC == 3) {
            printf("\nIndustrial");
            printf("\n\nDigite o numero do consumidor: ");
            scanf("%i", &consumidor[i].num);
            printf("\nDigite a quantidade de kWh consumidos durante o mes: ");
            scanf("%f", &consumidor[i].kwh);
            total = consumidor[i].kwh * 0.7;
            //O total do valor com tarifa, ou seja o total + tarifas
            totalT = total + 5.17;
        }
        float media = consumo1 + consumo2 / 2;
        printf("\nO total de consumo e %.2f\n", total);
        printf("\nO custo total e %.2f\n", totalT);
        printf("\nA media de consumo dos consumidores 1 e 2 e %.2f\n", media);
        i++;
    } while (consumidor[i - 1].num != 0);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/QsUHhG). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/izieujry-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/LoopVariable.c).

Uma solução um pouco melhor mas ainda com problemas:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    struct pessoas {
        int codTC; //codigo do consumidor para falar se é 1-Residencial 2-Comercial 3-Industrial
        int num; //numero do consumidor (vou colocar o numero referente ao cod para nao confundir)
        float kwh; //Quilowatt-hora
    };
    struct pessoas consumidor[16];
    float total, consumo1, consumo2;
    int i = 0;
    printf("Exercício desenvolvido considerando a tarifa do CIP - Contribuição Municipal\n");
    do {
        printf("\nDigite o numero do consumidor: ");
        scanf("%i", &consumidor[i].num);
        if (consumidor[i].num == 0) break;
        printf("\nTipo de consumidor, digite:\n1 - Residencial\n2 - Comercial\n3 - Industrial: ");
        scanf("%i", &consumidor[i].codTC);
        printf("\nDigite a quantidade de kWh consumidos durante o mes: ");
        scanf("%f", &consumidor[i].kwh);
        fflush(stdin);
        if (consumidor[i].codTC == 1) {
            printf("\nResidencial");
            total = consumidor[i].kwh * 0.3;
            consumo1 = consumidor[i].kwh; //isto não faz sentido mas deixei
        } else if (consumidor[i].codTC == 2) {
            printf("\nComercial");
            total = consumidor[i].kwh * 0.5;
            consumo2 = consumidor[i].kwh; //isto não faz sentido mas deixei
        } else if (consumidor[i].codTC == 3) {
            printf("\nIndustrial");
            total = consumidor[i].kwh * 0.7;
        }
        float totalT = total + 5.17;
        float media = consumo1 + consumo2 / 2; //isto não faz sentido mas deixei
        printf("\nO total de consumo e %.2f\n", total);
        printf("\nO custo total e %.2f\n", totalT);
        printf("\nA media de consumo dos consumidores 1 e 2 e %.2f\n", media);
        i++;
    } while (i == 16);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/18gLEO). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/jebmcdwi-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/LoopVariable2.c).

Comment: No codeblock no meu note compilou normalmente, entendi o que fez. Obrigada pela ajuda. Sou iniciante, muita coisa tenho que aprender ainda, por isso que ele ta bem diferente. Obrigada mesmo assim! ;)

Comment: A solução que você escolheu sequer faz o que está no enunciado e ela não resolve de fato o problema que você tem. Mas é uma opção sua escolher o que quiser ficar com a solução errada.

Comment: E o fato de compilar em um compilador, não significa que está certo, apenas que este compilador deixar passar erros que vão trazer problemas em qualquer situação não trivial, ou seja, está aprendendo do jeito errado.

Comment: Entendi, sempre é bom aprender mais. Obrigada ;)

Answer (score 2):

O problema aqui é  que no inicio do seu **do .... while** você esta armazenando o valor digita dentro de **consumidor[i].codTC** e no seu while você valida se o valor de **consumidor[i].num** é diferente de zero.

Porém como o valor digitado em **consumidor[i].codTC** foi zero ele não passa em nenhum de seus ifs e logo não seta o valor zero dentro de **consumidor[i].num** fazendo assim o seu while retornar false e continuar a execução.